# User Search Strategy Mobile Dev

Tags: algorithm, performance, search, mobile

I want to implement a search feature on my app that re-filters upon each new character entered into the search bar so users can search for other users. This is a fairly common feature on apps, but as a beginner it would seem like a very computationally complex process. It would seem that one of two things happen:

1. For each new character typed, the frontend queries the backend, which applies filter and returns.
2. The frontend loads all (or many) possible results beforehand and updates filter on the stored info as new characters are entered.

It would seem that 1) would have time complexity issues, as it makes O(n) queries (where n is number of characters) per search. This is especially problematic because it's expected that the filtered search results update near instantaneously. Additionally, my average query time is probably slower than most, as I'm using a three tier architecture (frontend<->server<->graph database)

I don't like 2)--at least in its straightforward form--as the number of possible results can get very large. We can reduce the space complexity of this by querying only for a limited set of user attributes (perhaps only `uid` and name, and fetching details on the fly if needed), but the point remains.

Things get more interesting if we modify 2) to load only a sample of users (and here we can use data like Location as well as ML/AI to select). The problem with this is that the searching user could always be looking for someone we didn't select. It would be a horrible (even if rare) experience for a user to know their friend was on the app but was unable to find them because our algorithm was only accurate for 99% of searches.

I am sure this is possible--other apps seem to pull it off--so what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should avoid to query the server for each character typed. Most of the times the user types a bounce of chars very fast without looking at suggested results, especially because with few chars the results wouldn't be specific enough. All the autocompletion systems adopt both of the following:

- query only if the string is at least 2-3 chars long;
- query only if the user is not typing more, i.e. after 300ms from the last type.

To get all the pertinent results without huge data transfer you could implement a progressive data load. Just load enough results to fill the page height, then as the user scrolls down load more results. However if you reach a high number of results you should stop retrieving them and ask the user to type a more specific search.

If you want to make your users happy, try to sort the result by relevance. For example if you know where the users are located you may sort the results by distance, because if I live in Italy and I search for "Ste" it is more likely my friend is Stefano who lives in Rome, than Steve who lives in NY.